# Why does Spring 4 think a String parameter is an array of Strings in a request method?

Tags: java, spring

We've been using Spring 3 for many years. It works fine.

We want to upgrade to Spring 4. Getting it to compile and launch was straightforward, but we've been blocked for a couple of days by a weird problem where it changes a parameter from a String to an array of Strings, and then can't match the signature (because the request method doesn't have an array of Strings).

The request method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "wrongUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object wrongUser(Model model, HttpServletRequest req, @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = false) String userId, @RequestParam(value = "email", required = false) String email, @RequestParam(value = "locale", required = false) String localeParam){
```

We see it getting mapped in the logs:

```
20180201.182604 Th I - 0 HandlerMapping Mapped URL path [/*/login/wrongUser] onto handler 'loginController'
```

Just before redirecting to that endpoint, we log the URL we're redirecting to:

```
/app/login/0 LoginHandler redirect with [?userId=myuser] and URL [/prefix/login/wrongUser?userId=myuser]
```

In Chrome, we see the request URL:

```
Request URL:https://prefix/login/wrongUser?myuser
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
userId:myuser
```

And we see this error in the logs:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/0/login/wrongUser', method 'GET', parameters map['userId' -> array<String>['myuser']]
```

We think the problem is the array, which wouldn't match the request method.

Why is Spring 4 converting the request parameter to an array?

We haven't found anything about this online.

Comment: To test your thinking, why not duplicate the method and make userId and array then see if you get the same error.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but even if it works, we'd have to overload every endpoint in our system. But it's at least worth the experiment.

Comment: It's purpose would be to prove your thinking, that somewhere the configuration is expecting an array when it should be a String.  Hedging my bets I'd think it not an issue with Spring but some configuration/code/library that is causing you the issue. :)

Comment: We might be getting thrown off by the logging. Spring uses `ServletRequest.getParameterMap()` which always returns `Map<String, String[]>` even when there’s only 1 value for the parameter.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java#L675

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()

Comment: Also, overloading didn't change anything.

Comment: This turned out to be due to our subclass of AntPathMatcher that worked with Spring 3 but not with Spring 4. We suspect 4 fixed a bug in 3 that then exposed a bug in our subclass.